# Why did the mime type of a text file change after changing the contents of a text file?

Tags: php, mime-types

I am using a Linux Debian 8.4 server and I am running a PHP script which reads and parses 2 text files with the mime-type of

> text/plain; charset=us-ascii

and sends 2 emails based on the contents of the text files. In the text files they have the following structure:

> To: example@email.com
>
> From: example2@email.com
>
> Subject: example

and so on. When echoing the mime type of the first text file, it printed

> text/plain; charset=us-ascii

to the console

To test if my code was working properly, I changed the format of the email around to this:

> From: example2@email.com
>
> To: example@email.com
>
> Subject: example

Now after echoing the mime type, it printed this to the console:

> message/rfc822; charset=us-ascii

Why did the mime type change even though I only switched 2 lines around? Regardless of that, isn't the file always a text file and should have a text/plain mime type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably your php mail library or server is changing it.

Comment: But I have editted these text files before. Added lines, deleted lines, etc. Just seems weird that all of a sudden this happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are (or a library you are using is) determining the MIME type using [Fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) or by directly calling the [file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) command.

Fileinfo works by searching the contents of the provided file for certain "magic" byte sequences at particular positions within the file. As a rudimentary example, if a document's first four bytes are `0xFE` `0x37` `0` `0x23`, Fileinfo guesses that it is a Microsoft Word document.

Naturally this method isn't foolproof, and it's something of a challenge for text-based (as opposed to binary) formats which don't always have obvious byte sequences.

*message/rfc822* is an email format used to include an email message within another email, such as is sent by a mailing list or when you "Forward as attachments" in your mail reader. It's defined (rather surprisingly, like when you first learn that the "1812 Overture" was written in 1880) in [RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1.5) and it's just a plain text representation of the email content. It begins with the headers and the first header, and therefore the opening content of the file, is `From: example@example.com`.

That's why Fileinfo has concluded that your document is a message in an email digest based on the opening line: this is the pattern in the magic file that matches *message/rfc822*. It's really impossible to know whether the file is an email message or just plain text that happens to start with `From:`, so you get an educated guess. The [documentation for Fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.fileinfo.php) is explicit that it "is not a bullet proof approach".

You can write your own additions to the magic file. In Ubuntu they go in `/etc/magic.mime` (probably a similar location in Debian) in the format described by `man 5 magic`, so in theory you could override the *message/rfc822* match with a *text/plain* match. I'm not an expert on the syntax so I can't really help with this but there are online guides.

Or you could just trap this unusual case in your code, with something like `$mime_type = preg_replace("[^message/rfc822\b]", "text/plain", $mime_type);`. Not exactly elegant, but there you go.